# Cannot Remote Profile a Web App

Tags: azure, azure-debugger

I am using VS2015 with latest Azure SDK (2.7). I have an azure deployed debug version of my Web Api and using the VS Server Explorer I can navigate to my Web Api, and on the context menu, I can use "Attach Debugger" to debug with no problems.

But I do not see the "Start Profiling" option. What do I have to do to get this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote Profiling is not supported for free/shared sites. You will need to update your site to Basic or Standard to be able to see the profiling options and remote profile your site.